# Не удается изменить текст внутри <p> в js innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class='block'>
    <h6 id='text'>
        <font color='#FF586E' size=4>
            Проверка
        </font>
    </h6>

    <p id='profil'>
        <h4> Name </h4>
    </p>
    <p id="mes1">
        <h5></h5>
    </p>
    <form>
    <p>
        <input type='text' maxlength="302" size="40" placeholder="Ваше сообщение здесь">
        </input>
        <input id='btn1' type='button' value="Отправить" onclick="click()">
        </input>
    </p>
    </form>
```

Это код html

Теперь JavaScript

```
function click() {
   document.getElementById("profil").innerHTML = "Changed!";
}
```

Comment: P.S. Я новичок в веб разработке, знаю только python и java...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не можете изменить текст внутри тега `p`, потому что текст содержится в теге `h4`

```js
function myFunction(){
     document.getElementById('profil').innerHTML = 'Changed!'
}
```

```html
<div class='block'><h6 id='text'><font color='#FF586E' size=4>Проверка</font></h6>

<p><h4 id="profil">Name</h4></p>

<form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше сообщение здесь">
    <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Отправить" onclick="myFunction()">
</form>
```

Comment: Сделал также, но функция не выполняется... что может помешать?

Answer (score 1):

Измените название функции которую передаете в `onclick=""`. Не нужно функцию называть `click` или `onclick`, то есть:

```
function click() { // так называть функцию не надо
   document.getElementById("profil").innerHTML = "Changed!";
}

function onclick() { // так тоже не надо
   document.getElementById("profil").innerHTML = "Changed!";
}
```

назовите например `onBtnHandler()` или другим именем. Ниже пример с вашей версткой, изменено имя функции

```js
function onBtnHandler() {
    document.getElementById('profil').innerHTML = 'Changed!';
}
```

```html
 <div class='block'>
<h6 id='text'>
    <font color='#FF586E' size=4>
        Проверка
    </font>
</h6>

<p id='profil'>
    <h4> Name </h4>
</p>
<p id="mes1">
    <h5></h5>
</p>
<form>
<p>
    <input type='text' maxlength="302" size="40" placeholder="Ваше сообщение здесь">
    </input>
    <input id='btn1' type='button' value="Отправить" onclick="onBtnHandler()">
    </input>
</p>
</form>
</div>
```